# How to check the number of function arguments given by the user

Tags: functions, argument-patterns

Suppose I have defined the following function inside a package that can take 2 arguments.

```
f[x_,y_]:={x,y}
```

So, if the user gives `f[1,2]` then the output is `{1,2}`. But if the input is `f[1,2,3]` then the output is also `f[1,2,3]`.

I want to print an error message when the input is `f[1,2,3]`, but I can't figure out how to count the number of arguments given by the user.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CheckArguments.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can redefine your function `f` to accept a variable number of arguments (`x__`) and then check the length with `Length`.

```
Clear[f];
f::argerr = "Two arguments expected, but `1` given.";
f[x__] := 
  If[Length@List@x == 2, List@x, 
   Message[f::argerr, Length@List@x]; $Failed];

f[1, 2]
(* {1, 2} *)

f[1, 2, 3]
(* f::argerr: Two arguments expected, but 3 given. *)
(* $Failed *)
```

Another, probably a more appropriate way, as suggested in the comment by Jason, is to use `CheckArguments`.

```
Clear[f];
f[x_, y_] := {x, y};
f[args___] := Null /; CheckArguments[f[args], 2]

f[1, 2]
(* {1, 2} *)

f[1, 2, 3]
(* f::argrx: f called with 3 arguments; 2 arguments are expected. *)
(* f[1, 2, 3] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Why create an error if you already have the necessary arguments to proceed?

It seems everywhere I look coders especially new ones are eager to throw errors even when there are still easy workarounds. The end-user may not even be a programmer. Think of them as your customers. They may not think too kindly with using applications that are too sensitive to errors instead of self-correcting when possible.

My preferred approach is to always avoid error when possible. Here we can drop (not ignore) trailing arguments from evaluation but the end-user must always be alerted (warned) so he can decide if the output is still useful. A nice user-friendly way is to alert with an `Echo[warning message]` which looks very similar to error messages. These are hard to ignore but we can still proceed with evaluation.

Notice how much cleaner the code is now and as a bonus it is self-correcting. That is a *win-win* for everyone. You put out a better product and code is easier to manage.

### 1. A Good Approach: 1 Definition

```
Remove[f];
f[x_, y_, z___] := Block[
   {
    msg="2 args expected pos 3 not included in evaluation."
    },
   If[Length@{z} > 0, Echo@msg];
   {x, y}
   ];

f[1, 2, 3]

{1, 2}

>> 2 args expected pos 3 not included in evaluation .
```

### 2. Even Better: Recursive Calls

```
(* definitions *)
Remove@f;
f[x_, y_, 
   z__] := (Echo[{z}, "2 args expected, pos 3 dropped \[Rule]"]; 
   f[x, y]);
f[x_, y_] := {x, y};

(* input *)
seq = Range[1, 5] /. List -> Sequence;
f[seq](* this is just f[1,2,3,4,5] *)
f[a, b]
f[0, 0]

(* output *)
>>2 args expected, pos 3 dropped ->  {3,4,5}

{1,2}

{a,b}

{0,0}
```